# Solr Error -> "Cannot assign requested address (connect failed)" during frequently invoke Solr query

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am running Solr 7.1 on my Ubuntu system in port 8983.

It contains 8 number of cores and around 200 million document in each core. I am running a java code which do solr query to different cores simultaneously. According to my requirement it needs to invoke 10 000 queries in one second and it will continue for 3-4 hours. When I am running this code it is getting the following error after some seconds:

> org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Server refused
>   connection at: http://`10.*.*.*:8983`/solr/solr_core
>   
> .
>
> Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
>   `10.*.*.*:8983` [/`10.*.*.*:8983`] failed: Cannot assign requested address
>   (connect failed)
>   
> .
>   
>  Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Cannot assign requested
>   address (connect failed)

What I have explored that if I reduce the number of query per second or give some delay after an interval, it solve my problem up to some extent. But still I am getting this error after 1 hour running of this program.
As I am not an expert in Solr, I don't know about any limitations for which it is happening.

Comment: Have you looked at  the state of your sockets (`netstat`)? It seems that you might run out of available sockets/source ports (i.e. they're being closed fast enough to allow that query rate).

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are exhausting your local ports, AFAIK is due to keep-alive configuration if you open new connections very aggressively .

I'll suggest to take a look at SolrJ [HttpClientUtil](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/7_2_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpClientUtil.html), this class let you create a client defining your own PoolingClientConnectionManager configuration.